# Excel VBA Multiple range Print Preview

Tags: vba, excel

Hi this may little difficult.. Is it possible...

I would like to print Range B:D & E:T 
and B:D & V:AK .. I Tried with following code ... but Only B:D & E:T PrintPreview Appears

```
    Columns("B:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("E:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Columns("V:AK").EntireColumn.Hidden = False    
    Dim r1, r2, r3 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("B:D")
    Set r2 = Range("E:T")
    Set r3 = Range("V:AK")
    Dim p1, p2 As Range
    Set p1 = Range(r1, r2)
    Set p2 = Range(r1, r3)

    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
    ActiveSheet.Range(p1, p2).PrintPreview
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `Columns("E:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = False` twice at the top. Is it because you meant the second one to be `Columns("V:AK").EntireColumn.Hidden = False`?

Also, you could use your ranges in the unhiding:

```
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range

Set r1 = Range("B:D")
Set r2 = Range("E:T")
Set r3 = Range("V:AK")

r1.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
r2.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
r3.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = r1.Address & "," & r2.Address & "," & r3.Address
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA4
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks(1).Location = Range("U1")
ActiveSheet.PrintPreview
```

Comment: hi ... Thank you for your response... I want a print preview  **B:D & E:T** in One Page and **B:D &V:AK** in another Page

Comment: I've added that in now.

Comment: It gives BD , E:T , V:AK in separate Page

Comment: No, I cannot merge with **B:D & V:AK** it shows only in another page V:AK